# Update the content of Properties instance

Tags: java, properties

I have an instance of [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), named `props`. The key-value contents are as follows:

```
"a" : "apple"
"c" : "orange"
"b.1" : "tea"
"b.2" : "coffee"
"b.3" : "coke"
...
```

(Each key is unique.)

What I want to achieve is:

- I am only interested in keys `b.<number>`, I need `b.1` has value `water`.
- if there is a value `water` but is not with key `b.1`, instead, with key `b.<x>`, then, I swap the value of `b.1` & `b.<x>`.
- If there isn't a value `water`, I increase the number part of key `b.<number>` by 1, after which I insert `"b.1" : "water"` in the `Properties` instance.

I started to implement it with this code:

```
// initialize a HashMap
Map<String, String> propMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

// check what are the property key-values
Set<Object> keySet = props.keySet();
for (Object key :  keySet) {
   String keyStr = (String) key;
   String valueStr = props.getProperty(key);
   if (keyStr.startsWith("b.")) {
      // if it is not value "water"
      if (!valueStr.equals("water")) {
         // I get lost...
      } 
   }
}
```

I am not sure how to implement this in an efficient way without looping through the properties multiple times...

Comment: For your third bullet, do you mean you want to insert b.1=water and increment all the other b<x> values by 1?

Comment: @bphilipnyc , yes, exactly.

Comment: Ok, then my answer will work

Comment: Any response to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't readily see a way to do this without iterating twice (or in the case below, copying to a new `Properties` object), but the code below will work.  Also, I create another `Properties` object only when water is not found, so it may not be terrible depending on your use case.

```
private static Properties setUpProperties() {

    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.setProperty("a", "apple");
    props.setProperty("c", "orange");
    props.setProperty("b.1", "tea");
    props.setProperty("b.2", "coffee");
    props.setProperty("b.3", "coke");
    return props;
}

@Test
public void testProperties() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap(updateContents()); //just for logging
    System.out.print("Properties=" + sortedMap);
}

public static Properties updateContents() {
    // initialize a HashMap
    Properties props = setUpProperties();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap(props); //just for logging
    System.out.print("Properties="+sortedMap+"\n");

    // check what are the property key-values
    boolean foundWater = false;
    for (String key : props.stringPropertyNames()) {
        if (key.startsWith("b.")) { //only b keys
            String value = props.getProperty(key);
            if ("water".equals(value)) {
                foundWater = true;
                if ("b.1".equals(key)) {
                    return props;
                }
                else {
                    //swap b.1 value with b.x value
                    int digit = getDigit(key);
                    props.setProperty("b." + digit, props.getProperty("b.1"));
                    props.setProperty("b.1", "water");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (foundWater) {
        return props;
    }
    else {
        Properties propertiesCopy = new Properties(); //avoid a ConcurrentModificationException
        propertiesCopy.putAll(props);

        for (String key : propertiesCopy.stringPropertyNames()) {
            //increment all other b-values by one
            if (key.startsWith("b.")) {
                int digit = getDigit(key);
                int incremented = digit + 1;
                propertiesCopy.setProperty("b." + incremented, propertiesCopy.getProperty(key));
            }
        }
        propertiesCopy.setProperty("b.1", "water");
        return propertiesCopy;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the digit given a key from a Properties object (this is x)
 */
private static int getDigit(String key) {
    String digit = key.substring(key.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); //use period as delimiter
    return Integer.valueOf(digit);
}
```

You could also put in `equalsIgnoreCase` checks instead.

Comment: Your function `setUpProperties()` should be a for loop, because I don't know the content of the properties, that is just my example. So, there will be three for-loops needed in total.

Comment: Hmm - ok!  Wouldn't have known that from your original post.  A lot of the time, you'd be reading and writing .properties files, so that implementation isn't part of this answer.